# How to modify trace service programmatically at runtime in Websphere V7?

Tags: java, websphere

As you know, Was V7 has the function to configure log in Admin console. But, I want to modify these configurations via my code. So, does it exist some APIs to help me to implement this in Was V7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [AdminClient](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v5r1//index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.exp.doc/info/exp/ae/rjmx_adminclient.html) to look up the [TraceService MBean](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/public_html/mbeandocs/index.html) and update the trace string via that interface.